# What's the difference between the noexcept keyword and _NOEXCEPT macro?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, noexcept

I'm a beginner to C++ and I'm learning about some of the C++11 features. One thing I noticed was that in some parts of the Visual C++ stdlib, the authors used the `_NOEXCEPT` macro instead of the `noexcept` keyword. Hovering over the macro says `#define _NOEXCEPT noexcept`, so I'm a bit confused what the point of it is. What's the difference between the two, and should I prefer one over the other?

---

**EDIT:** I just searched for it on GitHub and it looks like [clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/8f6e763c49701838c47ab105e81634fc21bc77cf/src/new.cpp#L69) uses it as well, so it isn't a Visual C++ specific macro.

Comment: Looking at your standard library implementation is fine. Do not use it as a guide to how to write your own code.

Comment: If you toggle c++11 support, will the macro the be defined as (deprecated) [`throw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_NOEXCEPT` is not a standard macro. That's indicated by the leading underscore, which says this belongs to the implementation.

Most probably this macro was defined as `throw()` until the Visual C++ compiler gained support for the `noexcept` keyword introduced in C++11.

I.e., that it was originally provided as a means to write code that would be compatible with more than one version of the compiler. In a similar vein one might define a macro like `CPPX_NORETURN` to use compiler-specific means to indicate a no-return function, where C++ attribute `[[noreturn]]` is not supported. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

Macros everywhere. There are many different reasons to define macros. A common reason is to write code which can be compiled on different C or C++ compilers with minimum changes.

For example, assume there is a code which should be able to compile in a compiler that doesn't support `noexcept`. Instead of writing two separate codes, you can use the keyword as a macro:

```
#define _NOEXCEPT noexcept
```

Then, for compilers which don't have `noexcept` you can simply disable `_NOECXEPT` (even though it could be done automatically with conditional macros).

And, welcome to the C/C++ world...